# How to HTTPS call for Mailgun mail services (update)

Tags: objective-c, curl, mailgun

I need to use mailgun api in objective-c Mac OS X. I did try different solution without success. A possible solution I think is to convert the cUrl call with NSURL. so any help for achieve this is largely valued. thanks for your time

```
 curl -s --user 'api:key-0000000000000000000' \
 https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox000000000000000.mailgun.org/messages \
 -F from='Excited User <mailgun@sandbox000000000000000.mailgun.org>' \
 -F to=me@gmail.com \
 -F to=bar@example.com \
 -F subject='Hello' \
 -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!'
```

Comment: What have you tried? Those seem to be request parameters, and MailGun should have documentation as well.

Comment: Well `curl` is a command line utility and `NSURL` is an Objective-C class, so "convert" doesn't quite cover it.  What you're asking is how to construct an HTTP POST request, which is pretty broad.

Comment: Right, i want to construct an HTTP POST REQUEST with User and Key parameter. For Jon: i have tried mail gun objective-c library...